# Optimal way to create/spawn multiple sprites in mini2dx(subset of libgdx)

Tags: libgdx, sprites

What is optimal way to spawn new sprites with different sizes in mini2dx(subset of libgdx)?
Currently I am maintaining ArrayList of enemy sprites

```
private ArrayList<Sprite> enemies = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
```

In the generateEnemies method:

```
private void generateEnemies() {
    // How many enemies to spawn max?? X
    for (int i=0; i<=5;i++) {
        float size = (float) Math.random() * 3;
        float speed = (float) Math.random() * 3;
        float y = (float )Math.random() * Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        enemies.add(new Enemy(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("gfx/enemy.png"))));
        enemies.get(i).setScale(size);
        enemies.get(i).setSpeed(speed);
        enemies.get(i).setPosition(0,  y);
    }
}
```

In render method:

```
for (int i = 0;i<=5;i++) {
    g.drawSprite(enemies.get(i), collisionPoint.getRenderX(), 
    collisionPoint.getRenderY());
}
```

Although I seems to render the enemy but there is no control over the enemy sprite to respawn.
Is there any optimal way to do it?

Comment: Everything looks fine, what do you mean by "there is no control over the enemy sprite to respawn" ? Because piece of code here doesn't implement that functionality

Comment: Thank god someone replied.
Actually.By saying "there is no control" that means I am able to spawn say 100 of enemies but I have no control to apply logic,destory,set special properties to it.

Comment: You have to wrap your sprite in a class to apply some logic to it. By having an Ennemy class extending sprite for example, this way you can have your own logic inside this class